# Styling a selected ListViewItem in Windows 8 CP

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to change the appearance of the Border of the selected Item in the picture linked below.

[image]

I've already been looking around on msdn.com and on the internet, but I've found nothing useful.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you using WPF or a Metro XAML app? They are completely separate frameworks but you tagged this with both.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The selection appearance is part of the ControlTemplate for ListViewItem. To modify the template for an entire ListView use the ItemContainerStyle to apply a Style to each item, which can contain a modified version of the template.

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
            ...
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

The default template for ListViewItem is pretty complex so in order to preserve as much of the default behavior as possible and give you a good starting point, it's easiest to use Blend to create a copy for you.

In Blend, right-click your ListView and select:

**Edit Additional Templates -> Edit Generated Item Container -> Edit A Copy...**

and it will create a Style for you in the form above with the default template filled in. The selection appearance uses a few different elements in the template which you may want to modify - these can be seen by selecting the Selected state in the States panel in Blend and drilling into the highlighted items in the Objects panel.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. I keep forgetting that I have Blend for Visual Studio to help with this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I've found out another solution that might be helpful for others: override specific brush resources in `App.xaml`. It works without cloning any default style, and is just as simple as:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="myColor1"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="myColor2"/>
```

Of course, there are more bushes that can be overriden, and a list of them can be found here: [ListViewItem styles and templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709921.aspx).

Note that this approach changes the appearance for ALL ListViews in the application.