# How to change a ListViewItem with ContentTemplateSelector Dynamically (after load)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

I have a ListView, with ListViewItem s being properly formatted using ItemTemplateSelector when the control first loads content.  The data is properly coded using INotifyPropertyChanged.

My question is: How do I cause a single ListViewItem to update it's DataTemplate after the ListView has already loaded the data?  I'm not sure if I need to use a setter or a task or a simple binding.  Has anyone done this already?

My ListView code:

```
        <ListView x:Name="lv_src_gStream" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CVS_src_gStream}}" 
                  PointerPressed="selectPost" 
                  SelectionMode="None" 
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource postTemplateSelector}">
        </ListView>
```

This works well when the data first loads, but when a variable changes, how do I get the ItemTemplateSelector to choose a different template?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change single ListViewItem template dynamically after loaded.
But you can use ItemContainerStyle to custom your template on specific event,
like Unfocused, Selected, Pressed...
Here is a sample [How do I set a different background colour on item click of ListView for metro/WinRT app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291873/how-do-i-set-a-different-background-colour-on-item-click-of-listview-for-metro-w)