# LongListSelector performance is very bad when enclosed in ScrollViewer

Tags: performance, xaml, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I have a `UserControl` that needs to contain a bunch of controls on top and a `LongListSelector` below them. Total height of the whole `UserControl` may (and almost always will) exceed the screen height and in that case a whole `UserControl` must be scrollable.

My current setup is as follows:

```
<staff:UserContentControl 
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls"
    xmlns:staff="clr-namespace:MyApp.Helpers"
    x:Class="MyApp.Controls.RemoteHomePage"

    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}">

    <ScrollViewer>
        <ScrollViewer.Content>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Txt="Text1" Sign="@" />
                <TextBlock Txt="Text2" Sign="#" />
                <controls:Divider />

                <TextBlock Txt="Text3" Sign="~" />
                <TextBlock Txt="Text4" Sign="~" />
                <controls:TextDivider Text="Divider text" />

                <phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer.Content>
    </ScrollViewer>
</staff:UserContentControl>
```

This solution satisfies my needs but also there's a big problem: currently `LongListSelector` takes really a lot of time to load when amount of items it contains is reasonably large. It takes 8 seconds to process 300 items and during that time the whole UI is blocked. If I remove everything but `LongListSelector`, like so:

```
<staff:UserContentControl 
    ...>

    <phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector>
</staff:UserContentControl>
```

then `LongListSelector` loads almost immediately even with significantly larger amount of items. But obviously I need those other controls above it so the question is what can I do solve this issue?

(Also related question: I was worried that `LongListSelector` inside `ScrollViewer` could cause double scrolling or something like that but eventually everything turned out just fine in this regard. I'm not sure if `LongListSelector` somehow knows that it is inside other scrollable control or if something else happens that I'm not aware of. Some explainantion why it works fine, although very slow, would be much appreciated.)

Comment: You're doing it wrong.

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't use scroll viewer since it will make the longlistselector think it has an infinitely tall screen available and render all its items.
Instead to solve your usecase use the Header and Footer properties to add data above or below your list items.

Answer (score 1):

You can't force ScrollViewer to virtualize LongListSelector items.

So you need to mimic it behaviour by LongListSelector only.

Make the first item contains all you required elements form StackPanel (1'st itemtemplate). And other elements will be basic LongListSelector elements (2'nd itemtemplate).

Here is explanation how to set different templates to the items: [Styling a selected ListViewItem in Windows 8 CP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623938/styling-a-selected-listviewitem-in-windows-8-cp)